# Knockout AJAX data sent to C# controller is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to post a list of colors (id numbers) to a test function in my controller. I know the data is being sent and looks like it's formed correctly.

When I send the data fiddler shows this:

```
[{"ID":"15","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":"1"},   
{"ID":"21","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":"1"}]
```

Knockout AJAX post:

```
        SendData = ko.toJSON(self.AddColors) ;
        alert(SendData);

        $.ajax({
            ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: '/EditColor/PostColors',
            data: SendData
        }).success(function (data) {

        });
```

The data class I'm using:

```
public class AjaxColorList
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string bNotPermanent { get; set; }
}
```

The controller function:
(I also tried public JsonResult PostColors(String AddColors just to see if anything would come through)

```
    public JsonResult PostColors(List<Helpers.AjaxColorList> AddColors)
    {
        var ColorList = AddColors;  // breakpoint set here
        ....
    }
```

At the breakpoint in the function above I see that AddColors is null.  I made sure the fields in the JSON query match what's in the data class.  What am I missing?

I also changed the code so that it's passing only one object to the controller to verify that it can receive something... anything.

The added controller function looks like this:

```
    public JsonResult RequestAddColor(Helpers.AjaxColor AddColor)
    {
        var color = AddColor; // breakpoint here


         ...
    }
```

Fiddler shows this:

```
{"ID":"11","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":"false"}
```

But the controller shows all vars as null.

This has got to be something stupid / simple that I'm missing.  Can anyone see the error in my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this format for your ajax call, I recreated the scenario and this is working for me:

```
          $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/PostColors',
                contentType: "application/json",
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("FAIL: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log("SUCCES");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hmm.  If I do that it wants me to add system.http.web; which collides with system.mvc.web;.  if I comment out system.mvc.web to work with system.http.web instead I get all kinds of compiler errors listed because the controller, viewresult, etc.. no longer are defined...

Comment: That may be for a WebAPI controller, this post suggest adding [HttpPost] attribute just before the name of the method. http://vault.lozanotek.com/archive/2010/04/16/posting_json_data_to_mvc_controllers.aspx

Comment: This example is putting the array data into the name of the parameter that the method expects: http://forums.asp.net/t/1629342.aspx?Get+an+Array+from+Jquery+Ajax+post

Comment: It's exactly what I'm doing in the first iteration with arrays which is why I'm confused why the data is null when it clearly shows in fiddler it's being sent.

Comment: Try the updated ajax format above and see if that works for you.

Comment: From what I understand, stringify won't work with knockout... I've tried using that in the past but I don't see any data getting sent to the controller.

Comment: I just tried it again and indeed the data set is null in the javascript.  The reading I've done is that stringify and knockout are not compatible...

Comment: The knockout documentation indicates that stringify is supported: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

Comment: I put a working example, full solution up on github. See if this helps you out: https://github.com/swestfall21/PostTestRepo

Comment: That works; I'll dissect it to see where I'm going wrong. Thanks!  I'll post my results when I figure it out.

Comment: I've got to be absolutely insane; your code works and compared to mine it's virtually identical minus the knockout changes which shouldn't make much of a difference...

Comment: I wired your source into mine and was able to get the data to transfer after commenting out a lot of code.   At least I know now it's in my javascript somewhere so I'm going to re-wire the page. thanks for your help; MOST APPRECIATED!